# Perl match a value, then match the count of values of each value

Tags: perl

So I have some data in tab delimited form:

```
Windows Department1 Enterprise
Windows Department1 Home
Linux   Department2 Santiago
Windows Department1 Professional
Windows Department1 Enterprise
Windows Department2 Enterprise
```

In this case I need to match the first column first and get the count of each value in the 2nd and 3rd columns. Sort of to match the number of exact matches.
So to end up with something like:

```
Windows Department1 Enterprise = 2
Windows Department2 Professional = 1
Linux   Department2 Santiago = 1
Windows Department3 Home = 1
Windows Department2 Enterprise = 1
```

So I tried loads of things, with this being the last attempt and I got many different unwanted results:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my %seen;
my $count = 0;
while (<INPUTFILE>) {
my ($app,$dep,$name) = split(/\t/,$_);
   if ($app.$dep.$name eq 'Windows.Department1.Professional') {
   unless ($seen{$app.$dep.name}++) {
     $count++;
      }
   }
}
print $app . " " . $dep . " " . $name . " " . $count++
```

But this does not do remotely what I want. and just prints the last values with a count. I want to set the `$app` unique once, then match both the second and third values to get a count. Other than that, I need to manually match each item with `eq` and the example above does not remotely show the amount of data in the file, so this will become a pain. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First construct a hash keyed by what you want to count uniquely: the combination of $app, $dep, and $name. You can use a combined key for this but let's use a multidimensional hash to keep the keys separate for later. Each intermediate level will automatically be [autovivified](https://perldoc.pl/perlref#Using-References) when we increment a count.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open my $input, '<', $filename or die "open $filename failed: $!";
my %counts;
while (my $line = <$input>) {
  chomp $line; # otherwise trailing field will contain a newline
  my ($app, $dep, $name) = split /\t/, $line;
  $counts{$app}{$dep}{$name}++;
}
```

Then iterate through the hash to print out each count.

```
foreach my $app (sort keys %counts) {
  my $app_counts = $counts{$app};
  foreach my $dep (sort keys %$app_counts) {
    my $dep_counts = $app_counts->{$dep};
    foreach my $name (sort keys %$dep_counts) {
      my $count = $dep_counts->{$name};
      print "$app $dep $name $count\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you. I am just getting a whole bunch of `Use of uninitialized value $dep in hash element at count_matches.pl line 11, <$input> line 1` as output.

Comment: Are you sure your input is tab separated? Does it contain any lines that don't have data? Try `split ' ', $line` to split on any space characters.

Comment: My Bad. I was still splitting on `$_` and never noticed you defined `$line` Thanks!

Comment: If  you know your fields don't contain spaces, use `\s+`, which will work for any combination of tabs and spaces as delimiters.

Comment: The `' '` special case for [split](https://perldoc.pl/functions/split) is similar to `/\s+/`.

Comment: @JoeMcMahon, Thank. My fields do contain spaces, so I have to split on `/\t/`